# Checkbox won't update from HTML form

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here my edit script on HTML form (my-edit-file):

```
<input type="hidden" name=<?php echo "toolbox" ?> <?php if($value['toolbox'] == "0") 
echo "unchecked='unchecked'"; ?> value="1" style="width: 40px;"/>

<input type="checkbox" name=<?php echo "toolbox" ?> <?php if($value['toolbox'] == "1") 
echo "checked='checked'"; ?> value="<?=$value['toolbox']?>" style="width: 40px;" />
```

My model update script always captured the second value "the unhidden" checkbox form. When the first data was "0" then I want to update by clicked the checkbox it should be updated to "1" but my models only captured the second checkbox form.

**MyController:**

```
public function update_data()
  {

    $role = $this->session->userdata('role_id');

    $id           = $this->input->post('id');
    $toolbox      = $this->input->post('toolbox');

   $query = $this->m_urfave->update_data($id, $toolbox);

    if ($query > 0) {
        }
    $this->session->set_flashdata('Msg', '<b><h3><font color="blue">Data updated</font)</h3></b>');
    redirect('urfave');
}
```

**MyModels:**

```
function update_data($id, $toolbox) 
{
  $query=$this->db->query("update favorite_tbl SET toolbox='$toolbox' where id='$id'");

 }
```

Comment: You have two inputs with a name of `toolbox`. And I'm pretty sure `input`s of `type="text"` don't have an attribute `unchecked`. Why don't you just use _one_ `<input type="checkbox"..>`?

Comment: Thanks @kerbholz first I was using one checkbox form, but I was confused if the first value was zero "0" from the toolbox value in database, and I want to edit the data or change it to "checked" the value must be one "1". If I'm using only one input form my models always captured "0" value. That's the part confusing me, and if the first value was "1" in the database, then I was editing the data "uncheked" it worked, the value was changed to "0" but not from "0" value to "1" when I edited the data from it form.

Comment: As per my knowledge if the checkbox is not checked the value will not get posted. So you are getting it in the controller. Can you please be more clear and tell me what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @beingprabhu When I was choosing the "Toolbox" option, I was tick off the checkbox, then it will add value "1" in the database. When I want to edit the data, the form showed the "Toolbox" was cheked. Then I was uncheked it and it worked, the value in the database was edited to "0". But if in the first place I wasn't choosed or checked the "Toolbox" checkbox in the add data page the checkbox was uncheked, so I wan't to edit by tick off the "Toolbox" checkbox but the value not changed, the value still "0" it should changed to "1" in the database.

Comment: Here's the simple way:

**1.** My input page: `Toolbox [ ] Cupboard [ ] Table [ ]`

**2.** I choosed: `Toolbox [ ] Cupboard [V] Table [V]`

**3.** I go to edit page and change the choise: `Toolbox [V] Cupboard [ ] Table [V]`

**4.** The Cupboard worked, it was changed into "0" value in the database, but not the Toolbox, it still "0" value, it should be changed to "1" because I choosed it.

Comment: Okay. Does the checkbox have name and value attribute? Did you inspect the HTML content in the browser??

Comment: @beingprabhu That's right. So I was trying to add one more `<input type="hidden"....>` it was taken from my add data page, but not working at all. My models/controller keep taken value from the "Unhidden" input checkbox form: `<input type="checkedbox" .....>`.

Comment: @beingprabhu Here's what I got from inspect the HTML content: `<input type="hidden" name="toolbox" checked="checked" value="0" style="width: 40px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="toolbox" value="0" style="width: 40px;">`

But in my detail page, the "Toolbox" option was not checked. Eventhough I was manually edit the data directly from the database/the table, I was changed the value from "0" to "1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have to modify your code as below

```
<form action="url-to-update-method" method="post">
   //this hidden field is to send 0 if the checkbox is unchecked as 
   //php post variable will not have checkbox value
    <input type="hidden" name="toolbox" value="0"/>

   //This checkbox is the one which is visible on the HTML page to check
  <input type="checkbox" name="toolbox" value="1" 
  <?php if($value['toolbox'] == "1"){ echo "checked='checked'"; } ?> />
</form>
```

In your code, the `hidden` input field has a "checked" attribute. There is no such attribute. Please correct it.

It may help you.

Comment: Do you know why you are using `<input type='hidden' />`??

Comment: to get the value "1".

Comment: For that why you need hidden field? You can directly set it to the checkbox as I did in my answer. Set '0' to the hidden field as it is necessary in case checkbox is not checked

Comment: I feel the form in which you are setting the checkbox value is edit form. In insert form hardcode the checkbox value as "1". That will definitely work.

Comment: Yes, your answer worked correctly, but if I'm editing the checkbox from "0" value to "1" it did not worked. Your answer worked perfectly in my detail page, but not in my edit page. The edit page showed or **get** the value from the database `value="<?=$value['toolbox']?>` it can be "0" or "1" (1 it will showed the checkbox was ticked, and 0 it will showed unticked). The problem is, when the checkbox was "Ticked" and changed to "Unticked" it worked, but not if the checkbox was "Unticked" changed it to "Ticked" the value still "0".

Comment: Please remove the `<?php echo $value['toolbox'] ?>` from checkbox value attribute and hardcode it to '1'. I made a mistake in my answer. You don't need database value in the value attribute. Just set the value to "1". It will definitely work.

Comment: I've modified my answer. Please check

Comment: Yes...it worked perfectly, now it can edit the value whether it is ticked or unticked. It's perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad that helped you. Happy coding mate.